# HTTPS returns 404

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate

Have setup SSL on Apache

The certificate is self-signed and generated with

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 9999 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private.key -out public.crt
```

## requests

```
http://domain.com - HTTP 200
https://domain.com - HTTP 404
```

## httpd.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public/api
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public/api

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /var/ini/ssl/domain.com/public.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/ini/ssl/domain.com/private.key
</VirtualHost>
```

## Apache modules

```
# apache2ctl -M
[Tue Oct 08 11:09:38 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:443 has no VirtualHosts
[Tue Oct 08 11:09:38 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
Loaded Modules:
...
 ssl_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

## log

```
[Tue Oct 08 12:36:34 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Tue Oct 08 12:36:34 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Tue Oct 08 13:14:13 2013] [info] Loading certificate & private key of SSL-aware server
[Tue Oct 08 13:14:13 2013] [debug] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(470): unencrypted RSA private key - pass phrase not required
[Tue Oct 08 13:14:14 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Tue Oct 08 13:14:14 2013] [info] Configuring server for SSL protocol
[Tue Oct 08 13:14:14 2013] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(469): Creating new SSL context (protocols: SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2)
[Tue Oct 08 13:14:14 2013] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(420): Configuring TLS extension handling
[Tue Oct 08 13:14:14 2013] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(836): Configuring RSA server certificate
[Tue Oct 08 13:14:14 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Tue Oct 08 13:14:14 2013] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(875): Configuring RSA server private key
```

Comment: What's in the apache log?

Comment: Which version of Apache do you use in that server?

Comment: question updated with log... is running apache2.2.22

Comment: Try changing the log level to `debug` as mentioned at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#loglevel and post the log when you request `https://domainname.com`

Comment: log level changed to `debug`.. have updated the log output in the question

Answer (score 1):

You can't do name-based virtual hosting in combination with SSL because the network connection is encrypted before the `Host` header is passed.

So you should remove `NameVirtualHost *:443` from your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the following to each virtual host it works

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
```